# Storing access token and refresh token NextJS

Tags: next.js, token, access-token

I'm trying to integrate one App built with Next.js and Salesforce Marketing Cloud. This integration use an OAuth. After the user had logged in, he is redirected back to the Next.js App with the authorization code, then a request is sent (with the code) requiring an access and refresh token.

[image: Authorization]

What is the best or correct (or secure) way to store the access and refresh token?

Can it be stored in the client? Or Should be stored in the ServerSide (in Next.js), creating a session with an HttpOnly cookie?

Answer (score 2):

HttpOnly cookie storage with CSRF tokens is the best way to store jwt tokens.